# A python coded telegram bot for reading messages

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I need to write a telegram bot with python as my python-class project. I've found out that I can generally do it bu telegram.ext lib. but I need help to know which classes and method can hand me for reading messages and bio from different telegram channels. Does anyone have a related code samples?

Answer (score 1):

They have a wiki which looks good, have a look through there:

Initial setup:

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API

Implementation of the API:

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot